# Prepositional Phrases as Subjects - Subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, subjects

http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/functioning_as_a_noun_examples/97/

From this page above, I found some examples showing prepositional phrases as subjects, but the predicate nouns are all singular like the ones below. So their verbs are, of course, singular.

> > 1) On a boat is **where I want to be**.
> >
> > 2) Beyond the backyard is **marshland**.
> >
> > 3) Under the couch is an **abyss where toys are lost**.

When we use prepositional phrases as subjects, is there the subject-verb agreement rule to follow?

If the predicate nouns are plural, which verb form should I use? Singular form or Plural form?

For example:

> > 1) Behind me **is/are** cute puppies.
> >
> > 2) Behind the man **stands/stand** two tall buildings.

What if there are two prepositional phrases functioning as the subject?

> > 3) Before me and under the sky **is/are** a scenic view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about what the subjects of your example sentences are.

> 1) Behind me is/are cute puppies.

The subject here is "puppies," not "behind me." This sentence is equivalent to:

> 1*) Cute puppies **are** behind me.

The subjects of the other examples are, in order, "two tall buildings" and "a scenic view." From there you should be able to determine the correct verb agreement.